# Github access rights for follow-up commits after successful pull request

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I wanted to fix a bug in a repository of which I am not the owner.
I therefore forked the repository, implemented my changes and sent a pull request.

The pull request was accepted and my branch was merged into the master branch of that repository. Also my username showed up in the list of contributors.

I now want to further improve the code that was merged into master branch  of the original repository.

My question is: Am I now allowed to just commit to the master branch of that repository (since the first pull request was accepted) or do I have to make a pull request again and wait for the reply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the owner of the original repo has given you write access (or made you a contributor), you will have to create another pull request.

Update your fork from the *upstream* repo to get the merged changes, create a new branch from there, and make additional changes. Push your branch to GitHub, and create a new pull request against the original repo.

If you intend to contribute to the other repo on a regular basis, you might want to ask the owner to give you write access or to add you as a contributor.

Comment: Ok, I updated my fork so it is synced with the 'master' of the original repo. But why do I have to create a new branch from my fork then? On github it says 'your branch is 3 commits ahead of otherrepo:master'. Can't I just create a pull request from there?

Comment: It is recommended to do all work for a pull request in a separate branch, just to be sure that you're not introducing any other changes. If your master branch is the exact same as the upstream/master, you can use your master branch. Otherwise, I would create a new branch based on upstream/master and make the changes for the pull request there.